# Android SQLite relative increase of column value

Tags: android, sqlite

Using SQLite db.update function, we can modify a record giving absolute values for records satisfying where clause. For ex:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("id",111);
cv.put("Field1",10);
cv.put("Field2",100);
```

But, how do I say Field1 = Field1 + 5, without using a separate select query to fetch existing Field1 value or using `db.execSQL(updateQuery)` ? (I deliberately want to avoid db.execSQL for update operations)

I want to avoid a separate query because, if multiple threads perform update on same record, there could be concurrency issues.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `execSQL()` method of `SQLiteDatabase`:

```
String increment = "UPDATE "
        + YOUR_TABLE + " SET "
        + YOUR_COLUMN + " = "
        + YOUR_COLUMN + " + 5";

db.execSQL(increment);
```